# Nested try-catch blocks?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

```
int main ()
{
    try
    {
        try
        {
            throw 5;
        }
        catch (int n)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "Exception occurred";
    }
}
```

This prints out "Exception occured" but

```
int main ()
{
    try
    {
        try
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "Exception occurred";
    }
}
```

This just errors. It seems like I'm doing the try-catch's exactly the same! The only difference is that in the first case I'm throwing an int, then a general exception, but in the second case, I'm throwing a general exception both times. Is the program confused as to which catch to go to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no such thing as "general exception" and you throw no such thing.

In the first example, you throw an `int`, then you **re-throw the exception that you are handling**. That's the meaning of `throw` without an argument.

In the second example you start with an attempt to re-throw an exception that you are handling. As you are not handling an exception at that time, you get an error.

Answer (score 3):

Your 2nd example terminates the program with a good error message (at least using g++ 4.6.1):

```
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted
```

This happens because you are trying to re-throw an exception, but since there are no active exception, the program terminates.

The current c++11 draft, in chapter 15.5.1 says this:

> In some situations exception handling must be abandoned for less
>   subtle error handling techniques.

Then in the list of cases when `std::terminate` is called is this:

> when a throw-expression with no operand attempts to rethrow an
>   exception and no exception is being handled (15.1),

So, the behavior from your 2nd example is well defined in the standard.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the detail since I'm a beginner and I'm slowly picking up on the differences between compilers and versions of C++